# Google Charts on IE: "Unable to set property 'data' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-visualization

The following JS exception is thrown while using the Google Charts' Bar Chart on IE:

```
Unable to set property 'data' of undefined or null reference
```

However the chart renders correctly.

I tried debugging, but the error is thrown from deep within the charts code. The file that throws the error is:

`https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/ce7a9bd29458c92c2c25b7969aaf2727/format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js`

And the line number is 244.

The error is thrown only on IE (tried both 11 and 9), and for other chart types as well.

Has anyone encountered this error before? Any ideas for how to debug this?

Comment: How are you invoking the service? That's probably where the problem lies.

Comment: Hmmm, just inspected my code again and found that I recreate the chart on every window resize. Changed it to only call `draw()` on resize and this solved the problem.. Thanks @Pointy !

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer (thanks @Pointy).

My code was recreating the chart every time the container was resized. On page load there were many resize events that caused the chart to be created multiple times in a very short period.

Changed my code to only call `draw` again on resize, without creating the chart again, and the error disappeared.